# How to handle Github authentication in nodejs for users with null email?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, github-api

I have the regular authentication flow where the user registers with a password and email and would like to add Github authentication but I noticed that the email field can come up with null if the user doesn't add it to their profile. I would like to know the best approach to saving users registered with Github on the backend

Answer (score 0):

Github's oAuth documentation doesn't lists the scope parameter that you can supply while get user code. Plus, you can't get it though the `/user` endpoint, you need to make an extra request to `user/emails`

1. To get the "Code", first redirect the user to
   `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id={CLIENTID}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URL}&scope=read:user,user:email`
2. Then to get the Access Token, make a POST request with the "Code" you received, like so:
   `https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id={clientID}&client_secret={clientSecret}&code={code}`
3. Now when you when you receive the access token, first make a request to the `/user` endpoint, and then make a request to the `/user/emails` endpoint. Make sure you pass the access token in the header with parameter `Authorization: "token {accessToken}"`

To get the basic user data make a GET request to this url:
`https://api.github.com/user`

And then to get the user emails, make a GET request to `https://api.github.com/user/emails`

You may get multiple emails in your result. The result will look something like this:

```
[
  {
    email: 'johndoe100@gmail.com',
    primary: true,
    verified: true,
    visibility: 'public'
  },
  {
    email: 'johndoe111@domain.com',
    primary: false,
    verified: true,
    visibility: null
  }
]
```

You can select the one that has the `primary` parameter set to `true`.